# Beamer frame with two columns and sequential uncover

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am trying to build a frame with 2 column. I have overlays in both columns and I want then to be displayed sequentially. I mean, first all the contents of first column (with the overlays) and then the contents of second column (also with its overlays). Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}

\begin{columns}[t]

\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{center}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\only<2->{\vskip2pt \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\only<3->{\vskip2pt \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\end{center}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{itemize}
\item<4-> aaa
\item<5-> bbb
\item<6-> ccc
\end{itemize}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To be specific, I want the structure:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<4-> aaa
\item<5-> bbb
\item<6-> ccc
\end{itemize}
```

To be replaced with something like:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\end{itemize}
```

I tested various approaches with `\only<>{}` `\visible<>{}` but nothing worked.

Comment: Just a side note: the `\column`s don't matter for the behaviour you observed.

Comment: You are right. I typed them because that was the layout that I wanted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\only<2->{\vskip2pt \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\only<3->{\vskip2pt \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\end{center}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[<+(3)->]
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The syntax `+(<number>)` adds `<number>` to the value of the counter `beamerpauses`.

This is even more automated since you don't need to manually control counters:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\onslide<+->{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\onslide<+->{\vskip2pt \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\onslide<+->{\vskip2pt \rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\end{center}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using `\only` instead of `\onslide` (depending on the intended effect).

Comment: The first solution works fine. In the second the blocks that are no printed become gray, what I don't want. Because I have also `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`, which I didn't put in the MWE.

Comment: @cacamailg then, you can use `\only` instead of `\onslide` everywhere in the second solution.