# Beamer frame with two columns and sequential uncover of toc sections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I know that there is already [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73837/beamer-frame-with-two-columns-and-sequential-uncover) question, but I couldn't apply the answer on my problem:

I want to uncover the sections that first section, than second section, ... , than 10th section will uncover in toc if possible with the `<+->` syntax.

Here the MWE, which will uncover both sides at same time...:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline splitted}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[pausesections,sections={1-5}]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[pausesections,sections={6-}]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\section{Test1}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test2}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test3}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test4}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test5}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test6}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test7}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test8}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test9}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test10}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline splitted}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
            \tableofcontents[pausesections,sections={1-10}]
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}


\section{Test1}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test2}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test3}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test4}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test5}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test6}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test7}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test8}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test9}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\section{Test10}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{frame} 
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]